# Is it safe to recook partially cooked steak the next day?

Tags: food-safety, steak

I prepared one steak too many yesterday.

One of the steaks went into the oven (from about room temperature) for 7 minutes, but then we never pan seared it after.

We let it cool, and it's been in the fridge.

Is it safe now to fully cook the partially cooked steak? I'm not sure that the 7 minutes did much to "cook" it (at 370)

If so, what's the best way to now cook it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

you can reheat it in a frying pan, or... if it's not raw inside, slice it for steak salad or sandwiches.  not bad.

Comment: Hello jchanse and welcome! This question deals with food safety. Without knowing how long the steak was in the danger zone, there is no way to know if the steak is safe to eat. On this site, we stick with food safety standards. That's not to say that we all practice what we preach, just that it's not responsible to give advice that could harm someone. As you are a new user, you may benefit from our Tour and Help pages. Both can be found in the 'help' dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: And as @Cindy already pointed you to our [help], note that there you will also find the links to our generic questions on food safety.